# wp_mail works with add_action('save_post', ...) but not an ajax action

Tags: filters, ajax, wp-mail

I have two actions.  One is after saving a post, so `add_action('save_post', 'on_any_post');`

I have a second action triggered via AJAX, so

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_saveTaskPriority', 'saveTaskPriority' );  
add_action( 'wp_ajax_saveTaskPriority', 'saveTaskPriority' );
```

In both `on_any_post` and `saveTaskPriority`, I have the following code:

```
$to = array('foo@bar.com');
$subject = 'foo';
$body = 'bar';

wp_mail($to, $subject, $body);
```

The only difference is, in the ajax function, I have `die('hi');` at the end.

I **KNOW** the ajax method is being called, because I am returning data and `console.log`ging it.  (Meaning I see 'hi' in the response of the POST in chrome developer tools)

I get the email from the `save_post` action, but not the ajax action.  What gives?

**EDIT**:
If I use straight up `mail()` in the ajax function, it works.

Comment: Try `die(var_dump(function_exists('wp_mail')));` instead of `die('hi');` What does that give you?